# How to run a validation check with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, validation, ionic-framework

I have written an ionic application and would like to know how(if) i can validate the ionic app. Much like validating HTML with W3C.

Is there any way possible to run a validation check on the app.

I have tried to run the application in the browser and run a google chrome local html validation, however the directives are still visible and haven't been generated to html.

[image]

Comment: which type of validation you want to add here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to validate the Ionic HTML in the same way you validate the HTML in W3C validator.

> however the directives are still visible and haven't been generated to html

Probably a bit of confusion here.
1. AngularJS directives will always be visible "as is" in the HTML code, they will not transform to anything. It's AngularJS itself to use them in its special way.
2. Ionic components are build with custom HTML tags, which means, for example  will not transform to anything else. All Ionic custom tags are defined in ionic.css file.